# Comparing the LDAP GUID with LDAP, getting GUID with ldap_get_entries?

Tags: php, ldap, guid

I want to use the GUID from LDAP accounts to identify these accounts in an application.  I don't get it binary safe.  If I compare these GUIDs with PHP with `==`, the result is true; if I use `===`, the result is false.

I thought this is the reason that I get no result.  If I search which phpldap after the GUID.

I got the GUID with this code:

```
$justthese = array("ou", "sn", "givenname", "mail", "pager","objectGUID");            
$sr=ldap_search($ad, $basedn, $filter, $justthese);            
$info = ldap_get_entries($ad, $sr);
```

After that, I save the vars in a MySQL database.  I've read that I should use `ldap_get_values_len`, but I don't know how to implement this in a query with multiple results.

The output looks similar to the from `ldap_get_entries`.

Am I only able to transform the result from `ldap_get_entries (guid)`, and am I able to compare these with LDAP?  Or, do I have to use `ldap_get_values_len`, and how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Consider comparing LDAP attribute values with matching rules instead of language comparison operators.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Programming Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Matching Rules](http://ldapmaven.com/2011/11/22/matching-rules-comparisons/)

Comment: i store the guid in a database for chache.
for compare i use the ldap functions...
the php comparison was only to detect my mistake...
the hex value of the guid in my db is in php == as the guid in ldap but not ===.

i thought this is the reason why the ldap

Comment: why the ldap_search says no result...

i compare this in the ldap statement with filter (objectguid=$mystoredguid) before that i convert the guid with hex2bin() in bin form